# Texture files zig-zag across object, never looks like it should

Tags: rendering, texturing, image

So here's my problem. No matter what texture I use or setting I change, my textures always zig-zag all over the object and it looks awful.

I've followed YouTube tutorials to see if I was missing something, but I don't appear to be.

I'm uploading a picture to show what I mean:

[image: Zig-zag texture image]

If someone can please advise me here as it's holding up my sponsorship logo.

Many thanks!

Comment: Long thin polygons are the worst. Pls avoid them. Also you need to unwrap your mesh to texture it.

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped the mesh? Maybe you could upload your blendfile?

Comment: I'm currently trying to but failing. The darn thing won't do what it's supposed to

Comment: I'll upload it now if I can...

Comment: you can upload it to some hosting service (e.g. pasteall or blendexchange) and put the link here.

Comment: I'm currently installing Drop Box. Won't be a moment. Thanks for the suggestions Gladys.

Comment: Here's the blender file folks. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbkrkpprg2bzp4v/FBCC%20My%20version%20GOOD.blend?dl=0

Comment: oh ok, because the uploaded file rendered perfectly.

Comment: Ah I see why it might do that. The blender file doesn't contain any of the textures I'm trying to use.

Comment: This is the one texture I'm testing on it https://www.dropbox.com/s/w632u90areznk8l/0009.jpg?dl=0

Comment: But whenever I add it as a texture, I get the OP picture.

Comment: Your problem is that the object is a curve, it has no mapping coordinates.

Comment: Is this something that I can fix? Or am I stuck with this basic object? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your curves into a mesh in object mode <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but I would make a copy of curved mesh just in case. Then I would go to the topview in edit mode and <kbd>U</kbd> --> project from view. Then you can add your texture to the mesh

Comment: It's our policy to give the person who solved the problem in the comments a couple days (let alone a few minutes) to post the answer.  See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/437/5705).